# iOS 5, waiting for location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have this method for locate the user and then change some numbers according to the Country he's in:

```
- (void) localizing {
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
DbOperations *dbOp = [[DbOperations alloc] init];
geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     //String to hold address
     countryCode = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];
     country = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
     NSString *s2 = NSLocalizedString(@"You're currently in %@", nil);
     lblLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:s2, self.country];
     [dbOp UsefulNumbers:self.countryCode];
     NSUserDefaults *loc = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [loc setObject:country forKey:@"Country"];
     [loc setObject:countryCode forKey:@"CountryCode"];
     [loc synchronize];

 }];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
NSUserDefaults *loc = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([loc objectForKey:@"Country"] == NULL) {
    btnUno.enabled = NO;
    btnDue.enabled = NO;
    btnTre.enabled = NO;
    lblLocation.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Unable to locate you", nil);
} 


}
```

The method get called by 'viewDidLoad' method but the very first time I run the app I can't get located.
If I open up Maps, let it get the fix and then open my app, everything goes fine.
I thought that maybe I don't give enough time to the app to get a GPS fix or maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: modified the code, not working yet.

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

DbOperations *dbOp = [[DbOperations alloc] init];
geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     //String to hold address
     countryCode = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];
     country = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
     NSString *s2 = NSLocalizedString(@"You're currently in %@", nil);
     lblLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:s2, self.country];
     [dbOp UsefulNumbers:self.countryCode];
     NSUserDefaults *loc = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [loc setObject:country forKey:@"Country"];
     [loc setObject:countryCode forKey:@"CountryCode"];
     [loc synchronize];
     NSLog(@"Country: %@", country);

 }];
NSUserDefaults *loc = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([loc objectForKey:@"Country"] == NULL) {
    btnUno.enabled = NO;
    btnDue.enabled = NO;
    btnTre.enabled = NO;
    lblLocation.text = NSLocalizedString(@"unable to locate", nil);
} 

}
```

Method locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation does not get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your code for reverse geocoding in the delegate method for CLLocationManager:

`– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`

Your current setup is trying to reverse geocode a location before an update has been dispatched from the location manager.

Consider setting up your `CLLocationManager` in your init method and then waiting for the delegate to be called before attempting to reverse geocode anything.

Comment: Ok, so I've allocated the CLLocationManager instance and set the delegate to self in my init method. Then, in viewDidLoad I start to update the location and in the -locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation method I've put all the reverse geocoding code. I'm trying the app on the simulator and the didUpdateToLocation... method does not get called at all.

Comment: I'm not sure about using simulator for location updates. There is a way to specify GPX files for location but you might have more luck testing on the device. Have a look at the simulator options for simulating a bike ride or a car journey.

Comment: I've tried to set the simulator GPS to 'Freeway drive', but it still doesn't work. Anyway, the user will not be moving while using this app. I just need to know in which Country the user is to get some numbers from a DB (like Police, Ambulance, Fire Dpt, and so on).

Comment: Regardless of movement, you should still be able to get a location from the `CLLocationManager` when your delegate method gets called. Have you added breakpoints in the appropriate methods to see where the issue lies? i.e.: no updates, or false results from the geocoder etc?

Comment: Ok, thanks to your hints I've found an example and I've been able to fix my code. Thank you.